# Construct sinusoidal functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone explain how do I determine if the amplitude is positive or negative? I dont quite understand the explanation given here.

[image]

Comment: By definition, the amplitude is positive.

Comment: @T.Bongers in this case, the answer is -5

Comment: That's $a$, not the amplitude. The amplitude is $5$, as explained in the solution.

Comment: Try drawing and comparing the two graphs: $y=\sin x$ and $y= -\sin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplitude is always positive, since it is simply the distance from the midline to the highest (or lowest) point on the wave.

As for the parameter $a$, you can tell if it is positive or negative by noting whether your function is increasing or decreasing at $x=0$. The function $\sin{x}$ is increasing at $x=0$ so if a negative number is multiplied to it, this will reflect it about the $x$ axis, and the new function will be decreasing at $x=0$.

Comment: can you explain in details? I still dont get it

Comment: @optimus Can you elaborate on which part of my answer is still confusing?

Comment: 2nd paragraph of your answer

Comment: You are trying to construct an equation for a function which is decreasing at $x=0$, but the $\sin$ function is increasing at $x=0$. So you cannot have a positive $a$ or else the resulting function will be increasing at $x=0$, which is not what you want. Making $a$ negative fixes this problem by flipping the function about the $x$ axis and thus making it decrease at $x=0$, which is what you want. Is this clearer? If not, which part specifically is giving you trouble?

Comment: how do I tell the function is increasing at x=0 or decreasing?

Comment: You can tell that $\sin{x}$ is increasing just by looking at the plot of $\sin{x}$. Then, multiplying a function by a negative number has the effect of reflecting the function about the $x$ axis. So, picture taking the $\sin$ function and rotating it around the $x$ axis, and you obtain a function that is now decreasing.

Comment: thanks. I plotted the graph of cos(x) and sin(x) and understand what you meant.